# Download Speed on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: networking, server, download-speed

I'm relatively new to Linux and am running a HP Proliant G6 ML350 server, for Plex, Sonarr and Radarr. Connected via LAN.

I have an issue with download speed, it appears like the speed is being capped on the server itself.

I have run the server through a VPN to rule out throttling but all it did is lower the speed further.

While running speedtest-cli I achieve around 240MB/s download speed. Which is what I should recieve.

The issue is with wget and Sabnzbd, they tend to max out at between 17MB/s and 28MB/s.

Could anyone help please?

Thank you,

Edit to show speed issues.

```
Last login: Sat Jun  8 15:46:07 2019 from 192.168.1.211
$ speedtest-cli
Retrieving speedtest.net configuration...
Testing from EE High Speed Internet (blablablabla)...
Retrieving speedtest.net server list...
Selecting best server based on ping...
Hosted by GTT.net (Slough) [21.24 km]: 8.113 ms
Testing download speed................................................................................
Download: 219.03 Mbit/s
Testing upload speed................................................................................................
Upload: 30.55 Mbit/s
max@server:~$ wget -O /dev/null http://speedtest.wdc01.softlayer.com/downloads/test1000.zip
--2019-06-08 16:09:54--  http://speedtest.wdc01.softlayer.com/downloads/test1000.zip
Resolving speedtest.wdc01.softlayer.com (speedtest.wdc01.softlayer.com)... 158.85.230.20, 2607:f0d0:3001:78::2
Connecting to speedtest.wdc01.softlayer.com (speedtest.wdc01.softlayer.com)|158.85.230.20|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1073741824 (1.0G) [application/zip]
Saving to: ‘/dev/null’

/dev/null             100%[======================>]   1.00G  23.7MB/s    in 56s     

2019-06-08 16:10:50 (18.3 MB/s) - ‘/dev/null’ saved [1073741824/1073741824]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> While running speedtest-cli I achieve around 240MB/s download speed. Which is what I should recieve.
>
> The issue is with wget and Sabnzbd, they tend to max out at between 17MB/s and 28MB/s.

You're confusing units. Speedtest reports speed in megabits per second (Mb/s). `wget` and sabnzbd reports speed in megabytes per second (MB/s).

One byte is 8 bits.

The 23.7MB/s reported by `wget` *is* 189.6Mb/s. 28MB/s is 224Mb/s.

So in short: you are getting the speeds you expect. You're confused by the units being different.